# moment js invalid date on heroku using laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel, momentjs

i'm using laravel and moment.js and i'm getting an

> invalid date

take a look

signup and make a post

http://morning-depths-45941.herokuapp.com

whenever i make a post on heroku and render the post.created_at. It works locally on my mamp, however when i make a post asynchronously it shows invalid date but on refresh it prints the correct time locally.

On heroku it just shows invalid date even on refresh.

on heroku my console reads the following:

**Console**

```
{body: "adadadad", user_id: 1, name: "Tim", created_at: null, user: {…}, …}
```

Here is the following code i have starting with html

**Html**

```
<div id="mypost" class="col-md-8 panel-default" ng-repeat="post in myposts ">
    <div id="eli-style-heading" class="panel-heading"><% post.user.name %></div>
    <div class="panel-body panel">


        <figure>
            <p ng-model="post.body" editable-text="post.body" e-form="textBtnForm"> <% post.body %></p>
            <p>   <% post.created_at | phpDate : "human" %></p>
        </figure>
        <span>

         <i style="color:red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="deletePost(post)" ng-if="post.deletable"></i>


              <button ng-if="post.update" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="textBtnForm.$show()" ng-hide="textBtnForm.$visible">
                Edit
              </button>

            <span><button ng-if="post.update" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updatePost(post)">Update</button></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Main script for moment.js highlighting the create post and filter**

```
var app = angular.module('eli', ["xeditable", 'angularMoment']);

app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});



app.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
});


app.filter('phpDate', function() {
    return function(input, format) {


        if (format == "human") {
            // Special case for formatting. If user asks for "human" format
            // return a value like "13 minutes ago" or "2 weeks ago" etc.
            return moment(input).startOf(input).fromNow(); 
        } else {
            // Covert the moment to a string using the passed format
            // If nothing is passed, uses default JavaScript date format
            return moment(input).startOf(input).fromNow(); 
        }
    };
});

app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', '$http', function($scope, $filter,  $http){



    $scope.myposts = [];

    $scope.addPost = function(){

        $http.post('/auth/post', {
            body: $scope.post.body, 
        }).then(function(data, status, headers, config){
            console.log(data);  
            data.data['user'] = {
                name: data.data.name
            },

            $scope.myposts.push(data.data);


        });

        $scope.post.body = '';


    };
```

lastly my server side of things

**PostController.php**

```
public function storePost(Request $request)
{
    $data = request()->validate([
     'body' => 'required|max:1000'
    ]);

    $data['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;
    $data['name'] = auth()->user()->name;
    $owl = new Post();
    $data['created_at'] = $owl->created_at;



    $post = Post::create($data);

    $response = new Response(json_encode($data));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 


    // return redirect('/home')->withMessage('A new post was created.');

    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your HTML code just change the date (with custom filter) part to:

```
<p>   <% post.user.created_at | phpDate : "human" %></p>
```

Keep everything else same & it should work.

**Update**:

It's showing correct time according to local timezone. Also for adding new post it's again causing problem, so change `addPost` method from your controller to:

```
$scope.addPost = function(){    
    $http.post('/auth/post', {
        body: $scope.post.body, 
    }).then(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.log(data);  
        data.data['user'] = {
            name: data.data.name,
            created_at: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        },

        $scope.myposts.push(data.data);

    });

    $scope.post.body = '';
};
```

Here I've only added created_at property to user object with value as current time. So newly added will show correct time (with that custom filter)

Comment: hmm it works but the it prints the wrong date, instead of showing "a minute ago, it shows 13 days ago." Does my moment script look ok ?

Comment: the console shows the correct date, just doesn't reflect that in moment.js, maybe its a timezone thing, idk.

Comment: @BARNOWL Yeah it's a timezone thing, and check the Updated answer

Comment: yeah it still shows 13 days ago, is there a way to include the timezone along with the `return moment(input).startOf(input).fromNow();`

Comment: @BARNOWL after execution of addPost? I can't understand why! Instead of dates I recommend just use timestamps that'll avoid confusions. from the above addPost code change create_at value inside user object of data to: moment().valueOf() instead of that formating & check once.

Comment: yes after adding a post it says a few seconds ago then on refresh it says 13 days ago.let me give that a shot one sec

Comment: yeah it still says `13 days ago`, its been driving me nuts

Comment: It's because you're storing date in database (or your any service) in the form of string so causing timezone change issue you should save only timestamp (& in UI format it to readable form so it'll not cause that issue). & if it says hours then I can imagine timezone issue but as it's showing days difference there's another issue also there which updating your added date

Comment: what should i change ?

Comment: @BARNOWL I don't know php but I'm guessing you're creating created_at value at server (php) side. Just save value which is only coming from client side (angular app). But surely it's server side code issue